# warning: already initialized constant ERB::Revision

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rspec-rails, rbenv

I do get these warning after I run `rspec`

```
/Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/erb.rb:259: warning: already initialized constant ERB::Revision

/Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/erb-2.2.3/lib/erb.rb:260: warning: previous definition of Revision was here

/Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/erb.rb:367: warning: already initialized constant ERB::Compiler::Scanner::DEFAULT_STAGS

/Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/erb-2.2.3/lib/erb.rb:369: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_STAGS was here

/Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/erb.rb:368: warning: already initialized constant ERB::Compiler::Scanner::DEFAULT_ETAGS

/Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/erb-2.2.3/lib/erb.rb:370: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_ETAGS was here

/Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/erb.rb:489: warning: already initialized constant ERB::Compiler::TrimScanner::ERB_STAG

/Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/erb-2.2.3/lib/erb.rb:491: warning: previous definition of ERB_STAG was here

/Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/erb.rb:830: warning: already initialized constant ERB::NOT_GIVEN

/Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/erb-2.2.3/lib/erb.rb:832: warning: previous definition of NOT_GIVEN was here
.......
```

It says that I have duplication in `3.0.0` and `ruby/3.0.0` files. How I want to remove this warning ?

Comment: It's like you've somehow imported two different ERB versions. Sometimes a builtin will conflict with a gem, so maybe ditch the gem version.

Answer (score 6):

try running `bundle update` then `bundle clean --force`